# Table wider than screen in Lyx when its width set to 100% of page width

Tags: tables, lyx, column-width

When I change width of table's columns in Lyx (for example: 30, 30 and 40% of page width in the case of table with three columns), I get result that I expected in PDF, but in Lyx editor this table is much wider than the screen. It makes any editing of tables in Lyx quite difficult. Is there a way to change how tables are viewed in Lyx? (as I said - pdf generated is fine, so no changes in this regards are needed)

Best regards, 
Pawel

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround (described below) for how tables are viewed in LyX, except for when you're editing the table. Since you're probably interested in a workaround that works when you're editing the table, I would say the answer to your question is "no".

The workaround is to select the table and go to Insert > Preview. This will show the table close to how it is viewed as in the PDF. For this to work, make sure that Preview is turned on: go to Tools > Preferences > Display and make sure "Instant preview" is set to either "On" or "No math". However, when editing the table, you must click inside the table and at that point it will be the same as you currently see.

I would suggest you file a ticket at https://www.lyx.org/trac for LyX to provide a better display in this situation. Choose the component "tabular" when making the ticket.